# Putting permissions to manifest of Android .aar library project

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions, aar

I am developing an Android project which includes two modules where one is a library module for producing `.aar` files and another is a sample app utilising the produced `.aar` file.

Thus, there are two `AndroidManifest.xml` files in this project. Say I am developing a Bluetooth library, so I put permissions for bluetooth in library's manifest file. By including this library `.aar` as dependency, can I omit the `<uses-permission>` tag in the app's manifest file? In other words, does Android app "merge" (may be not literally but semantically) its dependent `.aar` libraries' permissions?

My experience suggests that while some permissions tend to behave as above, others demand explicit declaration in application's `AndroidManifest.xml`. I would like to know if my assumption is true, if there are any resources or documentations clearly distinguishing permissions those can reside in `.aar` library's manifest and those required to be declared in application's own manifest file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As far as I know libraries' manifests are merged into the main manifest. According to this [document](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Merging-Policies) all permissions should be merged as well.

Comment: Thank you for specifying the document in regards to this topic. I might have to further look/test on why some permissions were fidgety. My experiences with permissions of varying behaviours in merge process has been a while ago, so things might have changed by now. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @Maurice thank you for the good question, happy to be of any help :)