# determine user location without any permission android

Tags: android, location, city

we are creating a library so we have to not using this permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

last thing i was reached,it was using bts towers,but it seems getting information from bts towers requires `ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES`.

so what we can to determine user's city or priviance

get bts info:

```
 TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 

 List<NeighboringCellInfo> NeighboringList = telephonyManager.getNeighboringCellInfo(); 

 ArrayList<bts> btss=new ArrayList<>();
 for (int i = 0; i < NeighboringList.size(); i++) { 
      btss.add(new bts(NeighboringList.get(i).getCid(),NeighboringList.get(i).getLac())); 
 }
```

Comment: Make it a AAR library project so the permissions will be handled correctly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664359/putting-permissions-to-manifest-of-android-aar-library-project

Comment: everyone who is using our library they don't want to use those permissions.we have to get user's city without using any permission.

Comment: APIs which access possible location information should be protected by the manifest permissions, as location is considered sensitive information about the user. Alternatively since you are looking for city/province level data you could try IP location based lookup but that would require INTERNET permission and a external server to get the external IP. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6077555/295004 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/274308/295004 but realize that what you are getting is the location of the NAT not the mobile device.

Comment: we also test the IP solution,but it's not true always,some ISPs provide internet to other cities and when we get the information,wrong city is given to us.